# Grafana plugin - CORS issue with REST API

Tags: ajax, datasource, grafana

I'm currently developing grafana plugin using Angular-1 and ES6, retrieving data from REST API and representing them in grafana. The problem is that as far as grafana plugin is working within the browser, it sends ajax calls to our REST API and they are blocked:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. The response had HTTP status code 401.
```

We were required to solve this issue without adding that header on the REST API side. One simple solution was to use **[corsproxy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/corsproxy-https)**.

But I'm curios to know whether there is some other way to use REST API within grafana. If I set up some datasource to my plugin, will it work as a kind of backend or my calls to REST API will still be AJAX calls?

Comment: Is your REST API running on the same server as Grafana? As long as they're on the same port you might be able to use the proxy option in your data source configuration. But the best option would be to enable CORS and whitelist the sites (i.e. your grafana instances) that have access.

Comment: Thanks, I used proxy option of my datasource and it fixed an issue. However, I still don't like this solution from the perspective I'm using datasource only for proxying, but still it works. Thanks!

Comment: Cool, you could post that as an answer to your question and select it as the correct answer. It would help the next person along with a similar issue.